# Output Select Join in PHP echo

Tags: php, mysqli, echo

Database structure for my data

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `folder_title` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `folder_title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `folder_description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `folder_title`
--

INSERT INTO `folder_title` (`id`, `parent_id`, `folder_title`, `folder_description`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'Blah', 'Blah Blah'),
(2, 0, 'Blah2', 'Blah Blah'),
(3, 0, 'Blah3', 'Blah Blah'),
(4, 0, 'Blah4', 'Blah Blah'),
(5, 0, 'Blah 5', 'Blah Blah'),
(6, 0, 'Blah6', 'Blah Blah'),
(7, 2, 'Blah2-1', 'Blah Blah'),
(8, 2, 'Blah2-2', 'Blah Blah'),
(9, 2, 'Blah2-3', 'Blah Blah'),
(10, 9, 'Blah2-4', 'Blah Blah'),
(11, 10, 'Blah2-2', 'Blah Blah'),
(12, 3, 'Blah2-3', 'Blah Blah'),
(13, 11, 'Blah2-4', 'Blah Blah');
```

Im using mysqli

I have tried this and it doesn't show anything. Blank page.

```
$query =mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT 
    p.id as id,
    p.parent_id as parent_id,
    c1.id as child_id_1,
    c1.folder_title as child_name_1,
    c2.id as child_id_2,
    c2.folder_title as child_name_2,
    c3.id as child_id_3,
    c3.folder_title as child_name_3,
    c4.id as child_id_4,
    c4.folder_title as child_name_4
FROM 
    folder_title p
LEFT JOIN folder_title c1
    ON c1.parent_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN folder_title c2
    ON c2.parent_id = c1.id
LEFT JOIN folder_title c3
    ON c3.parent_id = c2.id
LEFT JOIN folder_title c4
    ON c4.parent_id = c3.id
WHERE c3.id = 11');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

echo $row['child_name_1'].'/'.$row['child_name_2'].'/'.$row['child_name_3'].'/'.$row['child_name_4'];
}
```

The problem is I can see correct results when I run the query in mysql but I can't see any results when I run it in php. Maybe I'm just not doing something right. 
How do I get this to output the variables into the echo statement?

My end result I'm looking for is to pass a folder id and get all parents till the parent is 0.

Example:
11 - 10
10 - 9
9 - 2
2 - 0 Parent folder

and display like

Comment: What [error](http://us1.php.net/mysqli_error) do you get (if any)?

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($row)` from within the `while()`-loop?

Comment: maybe you are having some connection problem which is causing $conn to be null.

Comment: If I take out the WHERE statement I get a full var_dump but if I add any WHERE statement I get a blank page.